# Magento 2: How can I use two blocks in my homepage?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

How can I use two different blocks in my homepage?

this code doesn't work:

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test1">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id_1" xsi:type="string">slider-block</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test2">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id_2" xsi:type="string">footer_col_1</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument name would be "block_id" then the value would be different for both block like below

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
 <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test1">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id"  xsi:type="string">slider-block</argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>    
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test2">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id"  xsi:type="string">footer_col_1</argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer >
```

Comment: How can I set positions,  for example:
1. for slider-block left
2. for footer_col_1  right?

Comment: it works like a charm :)